# Kotlin: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

[image: code pic]

Im implementing TouTube Api in my android Project. Im getting error in below line on "as" before YouTubePlayerFragment, "This cast can never succeed ". Im using to initialize youtube player in my fragment. I already tried android.enableJetifier=true in gradle.properties but its not helpfull

```
val youTubePlayerFragment = fragmentManager?.findFragmentById(R.id.vidVieW) as YouTubePlayerFragment
    youTubePlayerFragment?.initialize(Config.getYoutubeApiKey(),monInitializedListener)
```

**Here is monInitializedListener code. It works fine when i used this in activity**

```
monInitializedListener = object: YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
                    override fun onInitializationSuccess(
                        provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider,
                        player: YouTubePlayer,
                        wasRestored: Boolean
                    ) {
    
    
                        if (!wasRestored) {
                            mPlayer = player
    
                        }
    
                        // player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL)
                        val mydef="BPGJUPcbQ58"
                        mPlayer?.loadVideo(mydef)
    
                        Toast.makeText(activity?.baseContext, "Fragment Visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
    
                    override fun onInitializationFailure(
                        p0: YouTubePlayer.Provider?,
                        p1: YouTubeInitializationResult?
                    ) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity?.applicationContext, "onInitializationFailure()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
    
    //
                }
```

**This is a fragment inside my XML**

```
<fragment
    
                android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
                android:id="@+id/vidVieW"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@drawable/orientation"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    
                />
```

**In logcat im getting this error**

```
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment
```

Comment: Can you please add your monInitializedListener code ?

Comment: @Bhavnik kindly check it now

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin doesn't allow nullable types by default. The problem right here is that the fragment manager can be null, and so if it is the whole expression will be null, but you're casting it to a non-nullable `YoutubePlayerFragment`. The solution, simply, is to change the cast `as YouTubePlayerFragment` to a nullable type by instead doing `as YouTubePlayerFragment?`
I'd also personally suggest that you check out the [Kotlin Documentation on Null Safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html)

Comment: after using YouTubePlayerFragment? im not getting error anymore but issue is the video is also not playing

Comment: @account That probably means that the youtubePlayerFragment is null. Make sure that the `vidVieW` fragment is added before you initialize it

Comment: Sir can you please elaborate your answer i didn't get it

Comment: the player fragment has not been added yet, which is why the video doesn't play. Add the player fragment before you call `initialize` on it

Comment: like this?
val details = FragTwoNew()
            details.setArguments(getIntent("BPGJUPcbQ58").extras)
            var fragmentManager = fragmentManager
            var fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction?.add(R.id.vidView,details);
            fragmentTransaction?.commit();

Comment: i think i didn't get how to add player fragment. Kindly send me the proper way to doing this. Im new in development . thanks

Comment: Yes, this should successfully add the player fragment. Check if you are calling `initialize` before running the `fragmentTransaction?.add(R.id.vidView, details)`

Comment: getting error  kindly check the screenShoots https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/13ddmhE65wBEo1-MbrbvIRMPe7X7wgUX9